# signature validation test using PHPunit

Tags: php, oauth, phpunit

I am developing authentication system using Oauth protocol and as per the Oauth standard, Once  you send an authentication request to your server, In response you get some set of oauth parameters including signature, timestamp, nonce, etc. Now my question is, How do I write PHPUnit testcases to validate if expected parameters are in place (please note that parameters can come in headers or in body or in querystring). After parameter validation, I also need to validate signature I received in response using my signature calculation method.

I am stuck at how do I mock response to validate parameters and then signature.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What format your response is? btw, nonce in response?!

Comment: response format is XML. Yes Nonce to avoid replay attack.

Comment: @CM: why it is in **response**? http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5849 --- after you checked it on the server side - you don't need it at all. As well as signature... There is no signature in response :-S

Comment: In my case, for authentication I redirect user to server portal and once user provides username/password, server will generate oauth parameters and send it to client.

Comment: unfortunately I can't get you :-( What I know about OAuth doesn't correlate to what you're talking about :-S

Comment: For authetication, client has only key and secret provided by server and client redirects user to server portal along with key provided by server. Now once user enters username and password, server calculates signature based on request and sends back to client along with token. Token is main identifier for client but before that client needs to validate if response is from desired server or not and for that all these validation is required. hope that helps.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question but I used known values to validate that my OAuth client library was functioning properly. https://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async/blob/master/tests/EpiOAuthTest.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i understood you want to write a unit test for your client to see if it correctly parses the response messages from the oauth server.

So you'd need to "mock" the server. (Or rather the method that fetches the values from the server).

You could create some fake "reponse" xml files and pass them to the class that is concerned with reading the response.

So you have your Response class that has a ->getHeaders, ->getQueryString and ->getBody (I just make assumptions here) and you need to mock those methods out to test your "parsing" logic.

I hope i got your question. If not let me know and maybe show an example? :)

Comment: yes I think you have understood my question. For mocking a response, How do I mock php://input?

Comment: Either you apply (or have applied) _separation of concerns_ then you don't _need_ to do that (because the object that reads out php://input is not the one that handles the data) or you mock out the data reading method on the object under test (that would require testing against a mock but is kinda fine in that case) or you have an extra property holing the "where to i get my data from" property (member variable) and you overwrite this in a test (maybe set it public by using reflection) and have your test data in a file).